# creating footer.php in wordpress thesis theme

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-thesis-theme

I am craeting footer.php file in thesis theme folder but the theme is not pulling that content so how to access the content of footer.php file in my footer area.

```
<div id="footer">
<div class="container clearfix">
    <div class="footer-widget widget_text" id="text-10">
    <h4 class="widgettitle" style="text-indent: 0px;">
 <cufontext>About </cufontext><cufontext>Liveagl.com</cufontext></h4>
```

Comment: which version of thesis are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to override your custom footer with thesis footer.

You can do it by adding below code in your `function.php` file.

```
remove_action('thesis_hook_footer', 'thesis_attribution');
function my_custom_footer() {
  //Your custome footer code goes here
}
add_action('thesis_hook_footer', 'my_custom_footer');
```

Ref: http://thesistutor.com/how-to-change-the-footer-content/

Comment: i am currently using thesis 2.0 theme